# .NET CORE - JWT Auth - is user valid/active?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt

I implement a auth system on my application with a jwt-token.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Token"]))
        };
    });

services.AddAuthorization();
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("info"), Authorize]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get()
{
        return (await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value));
}
```

And it is working fine! But know i would like to check for EACH request if the user is still validd and/or active. 
I wouldn't to add a policy because i would like to have this check on EACH request. Do you have any ideas?

**Try 1:**

```
services.AddAuthorization(option =>
    option.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddRequirements( new ValidUserRequirement() ).Build()
);
```

#

```
public class ValidUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public ValidUserRequirement()
    {
    }
}

public class ValidUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidUserRequirement>
{
    private static IUserManager _userManager;

    public ValidUserHandler(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue( ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier );
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(userId);

        if(user != null)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

But my ValidUserHandler is never called and the response is always 403.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this to ConfigureService:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ValidUserHandler>();
```